# Strange API response in DRF - works on server run, empties on reload

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a serializer and a view returning the amount of objects for two models :

```py
    class Lieu(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)
        adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
        code = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False)
        ville = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
        pluscode = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "lieux"
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.nom} - {self.ville}'
    
    class Artiste(models.Model):
        nom = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False)
        type_artiste = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
        pays_origine = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
        ville_origine = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
        bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.nom
```

The result I expect is something like that :

```json
    [
        {
            "lieux_count": 3,
            "artistes_count": 2
        }
    ]
```

Here is the methodfield base serializer in serializers.py :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from datamidi.models import Artiste, Lieu
```

```py
    class AllStats(serializers.Serializer):
        lieux_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_artistes_count')
        artistes_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_lieux_count')
        class Meta:
            fields = ['lieux_count', 'artistes_count']
            read_only_fields = [ 'lieux_count', 'artistes_count']
        def get_artistes_count(self, obj):
            return Artiste.objects.all().count()
        def get_lieux_count(self, obj):
            return Lieu.objects.all().count()
```

And here is the view :

```py
    from itertools import chain
    from datamidi.models import Artiste, Lieu
    
    class AllStatsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        aquery = Artiste.objects.all()
        lquery = Lieu.objects.all()
        queryset = chain(aquery, lquery)
        serializer_class = AllStats
        permission_classes = [IsAdminUserOrReadOnly]
```

The result is quite strange, two problems

1. When doing a run server, the values returned at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/allstats/` are correct, but iterated as many times as the total amount of objects :

```
    HTTP 200 OK
    Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept
    
    [
        {
            "lieux_count": 3,
            "artistes_count": 2
        },
        {
            "lieux_count": 3,
            "artistes_count": 2
        },
        {
            "lieux_count": 3,
            "artistes_count": 2
        },
        {
            "lieux_count": 3,
            "artistes_count": 2
        },
        {
            "lieux_count": 3,
            "artistes_count": 2
        }
    ]
```

2. The second problem : if i RELOAD the page (and the server still works fine), the api appears as empty. If i reboot the server, it works again on first load, then disappears on reload :

```
    GET /api/allstats/
    HTTP 200 OK
    Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept
    
    []
```

I'm a total beginner and wondering what i'm doing wrong. My requirements.txt :

```
    asgiref==3.2.10
    dj-database-url==0.5.0
    Django==3.1.2
    django-cors-headers==3.5.0
    django-heroku==0.3.1
    djangorestframework==3.12.1
    djangorestframework-api-key==2.0.0
    gunicorn==20.0.4
    psycopg2==2.8.6
    pytz==2020.1
    sqlparse==0.3.1
    whitenoise==5.2.0
```

Thanks for your help!

P.S.: the `isAdminorReadOnly` is custom permission which works fine usually and never caused any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty list is because of this line:

```
queryset = chain(aquery, lquery)
```

That chain() call only runs once, when the class is initialized. It returns an iterator. The first time it is used, it is used up, and subsequent uses will be empty.

Instead, implement a get_queryset() method that can return a new iterator each time it's used.

That you see a whole list of results is because this is a ListView, it returns a list of results for each item. That you then give it fields that depend on the whole table is something DRF can't know. I don't know from the top of my head how to do it instead, you should probably make a DRF View not based on the standard DetailView and ListView, because this is neither.

Also, instead of using Artiste.objects.all() etc directly in the count methods, it's probably better to use self.get_queryset(), so that if you have things like filters later the counts are also of the filtered list.